# MongoDB Object not getting deleted via. Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete a MongoDB document but it's not getting deleted

My schema is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const InvestorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        required: true
    },
    logoUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Investor", InvestorSchema);
```

and I tried using these but none of them removed the document, Also i'm running on `localhost` with no users and roles.

```
// Required models
const InvestorModel = require("mongoose").model("Investor");

const deletedInvestor = InvestorModel.remove({ _id });
const deletedInvestor = InvestorModel.deleteOne({ _id });
const deletedInvestor = InvestorModel.findByIdAndRemove(_id);
const deletedInvestor = InvestorModel.findOneAndRemove({_id});
const deletedInvestor = InvestorModel.findByIdAndDelete(_id);
const deletedInvestor = InvestorModel.findOneAndDelete({_id});
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: You need to resolve the returned Promise. i.e `deletedInvestor = await InvestorModel.deleteOne({ _id });`.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I thought the await wasn't necessary for deletion.

Comment: The `await` is necessary for any kind of I/O operation that is essentially an "async" operation. For NodeJS just presume **ALL** I/O is "async". Or of course, read the documentation, because it will tell you. Without `await`, nothing actually happens. Or rather your program probably exits before it has any opportunity to happen.

Comment: Just for completeness nothing happens unless you `mongoose.connect()` of course. And which *also* is "async I/O" and yo **must** await.

Comment: Thank you. Will await all I/O from now on :)

Comment: I would have hoped your "takeaway" from this would be to always consult the API documentation first. If the return type is a `Promise`, then you use `await`.

Comment: I did see the docs and verified what was the return type.

Answer (score 5):

```
  try {
   InvestorModel.deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId("563237a41a4d68582c2509da") } );
    } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here the problem is you don't specify what object from the collection you want to remove...
So you should use your code implementation like this mate

```
InvestorModel.remove({ _id: '563237a41a4d68582c2509da' },callback);
InvestorModel.deleteOne({_id: '563237a41a4d68582c2509da' },callback);
InvestorModel.findByIdAndRemove({_id: '563237a41a4d68582c2509da'},callback);
```